# How to optimise TensorFlow Lite so as to treat the computational graph from static to dynamic?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I am currently looking to deploy a dynamic neural networks model (a network that can adjust the width adaptively) to NPU via TensorFlow Lite. However, as far as I can see TFLite currently only treats the computational graph as static, can anyone suggest a solution to make it dynamic?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, TensorFlow Lite product support dynamic dimensions in the shapes. If your TensorFlow model supports the dynamic dimension inputs, the corresponding TensorFlow Lite converted model will handle the dynamic dimension inputs as well.